# How can I add startup timings to MiniProfiler?

Tags: c#, mvc-mini-profiler

I want to time Application_OnStart using MiniProfiler. So far I've been unsuccessful.  I tried to create a Timing and add it to the children of the root, but it doesn't collect all the data I want.  It also subtracts the startup time from the overall profile time so it ends up with a negative duration.  Currently the only solution I have is timing it myself with a stopwatch and adding it to client timings. This removes the client timings from the first request and adds the application startup duration. But I don't gain custom timings, etc.  Also since I use the AddProfilerResults method to combine my API profiles within my MVC profiles (for the MVC UI, they are wrapped in steps), the startup time for the API on the first MVC request isn't included, and it's basically lost.

```
            MiniProfiler.Current.ClientTimings = new ClientTimings
            {
                Timings = new List<ClientTimings.ClientTiming>
                {
                    new ClientTimings.ClientTiming
                    {
                        Duration = startTime,
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        MiniProfilerId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Name = "Application_Start",
                        Start = 0
                    }
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way we do it here on Stack Overflow is to create a `MiniProfiler` in the startup method, add steps to it, then render it to a static string:

```
public static string ApplicationStartTimings { get; private set; }

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // init MiniProfiler.Settings here
    // ...
    var prof = new MiniProfiler("Application_Start");

    using (prof.Step("Register routes"))
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    // ... more config and steps

    try
    {
        ApplicationStartTimings = prof.Render().ToString();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

You can then have a route to display these timings.  It's hacky, but gets the job done.

Edit - I added a [branch to my MiniProfiler fork which demonstrates](https://github.com/dixon/dotnet/blob/de3834a164fd578d995d84c3fe782c1f0dc61e38/Sample.Mvc/Global.asax.cs#L46) this working; here's the output on the main index page:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: How? This fails because there is no HTTPCONTEXT, so it immediately dies when you try using httpruntimecache. The application explodes into fire. Are you not running integrated mode? The property used for the cache is static, so I didn't feel like swapping it around all crazy.  Also you didn't comment on how to add it to the per-page profiler.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some working code.  As for yours blowing up, can you post the code you're using, please?  I'm pretty sure `MiniProfiler` construction and `.Step()` shouldn't be touching anything on `HttpContext`, but I could be wrong (project has changed a lot since I last looked).

Comment: I don't have a good suggestion as to how you could get these startup timings into all every pages'/ajax requests' timings - since they're only run once, we just have a route to display them.  You could add a link in the profiler's footer to this route, maybe even the link's text could have the total duration, e.g. [startup (100ms)]

Comment: Okay. Cool. I guess I can adopt this. I was asking how to add the profile from application start, to the request so that you see them together.  This won't capture everything I want, because steps internal to that would access MiniProfiler.Current.Step("") down the line. That stuff is lost. Everything gets lost. But, this is the best I get, I guess.